# imageStore in compute shader to depth texture

Tags: opengl, glsl, compute-shader

I can't for the life of me workout how to write to a depth texture using `imageStore` within a compute shader, I've checked what I'm doing against several examples (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35539344/image2d-in-compute-shader) and [this](https://github.com/progschj/OpenGL-Examples/blob/master/12shader_image_load_store.cpp)), but I still can't spot the fault. I can write to the texture as a Framebuffer, and when calling `glTexImage2D()`, but for some reason executing this compute shader doesn't affect the named texture (which i'm checking via rendering to screen).

*You can skip straight to the below accepted answer if the above applies.*

---

Below I've extracted the relevant code in a clearer format, it's part of a much larger project, which wraps common GL operations in classes with a bunch of error checking. But I've written [the project](https://github.com/Robadob/sdl_exp/tree/multipass) myself, so I know what is and isn't being called.

I have my compute shader, this is very simple, it should write `0.5f` to every pixel, (which in my debugging render would output as cyan).

```
#version 430
layout(local_size_x=16,local_size_y=16) in;

uniform uvec2 _imageDimensions;
uniform layout (r32f) writeonly image2D _imageOut;

void main () 
{
    if(gl_GlobalInvocationID.x<_imageDimensions.x
    &&gl_GlobalInvocationID.y<_imageDimensions.y)
    {
        imageStore(_imageOut, ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy), vec4(0.5f));
    }
}
```

I create the texture using

```
glm::uvec2 shadowDims = glm::uvec2(4096);
GLuint shadowOut;
glGenTextures(1, &shadowOut);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, shadowOut);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F, shadowDims.x, shadowDims.y, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

I configure the shader using

```
glUseProgram(computeShader)
//Dimensions
GLint location = glGetUniformLocation(computeShader, "_imageDimensions");
glUniform2uiv(location, 1, glm::value_ptr(shadowDims));
//Image unit
const int IMAGE_UNIT = 0;
location = glGetUniformLocation(computeShader, "_imageOut");
glUniform1iv(location , 1, &IMAGE_UNIT);
glUseProgram(0)
```

and finally I launch the shader with

```
glUseProgram(computeShader)
glBindImageTexture(IMAGE_UNIT, shadowOut, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_WRITE_ONLY, GL_R32F);
//Split the image into work groups of size 16x16
glm::uvec2 launchConfig = shadowDims/ glm::uvec2(16) + glm::uvec2(1);
glDispatchCompute(launchConfig.x, launchConfig.y, 1);
//Synchronise written memory
glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_IMAGE_ACCESS_BARRIER_BIT);
```

I've tried a few tweaks, but whatever I do, the texture remains rendering however I first configure it at initialisation.

There are no GL errors occurring (I have a preprocessor macro I wrap all gl fn's with), and although my actual executed code is more abstract than that provided above, i'm confident there's no bugs causing vars to be lost/changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can't for the life of me workout how to write to a (depth) texture using imageStore within a compute shader

That's because *you can't*.

[Image Load/Store](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Load_Store) can only be used to read/write [color image formats](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format#Color_formats). Depth and/or stencil formats cannot use it.

And no, you cannot use `glCopyImageSubData` to copy between color and depth images. Compute shaders can read depth/stencil formats, but only through `sampler`s, not through `image` variables.

Comment: Thanks, had assumed `r32f` would suffice, although in hindsight `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F` is automatically normalised based on the viewport (which isn't available in compute shaders). That's a shame. So I'll need to create my depth/shadow map as a color attachment in order to blur it with a computer shader.